# Canonical biblatex "version" question?

Tags: discussion

The recent `biblatex` update has caused (as many here are well aware) a problem with mismatched versions of `biber`, `biblatex`, and (sometimes) contributed `biblatex` packages. @moewe and I recently [traded some comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297649/8528) about creating an artificial question that addresses this since neither of us could point to an already existing question that might serve as a good candidate for this. (That is, I assumed such a question existed, I just didn't want to track it down.) Is this something that would be of use? The idea is that all such questions could be closed with pointer to the 'canonical' question and answer.

Alternatively, we could take an existing question and use it as a starting point. This [most recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297649/8528), e.g., might serve as a decent candidate.

Comment: Just one thing to ponder that I glossed over in the comments is that the exact question we talk about is a bit special because it is about `biblatex` changes that break backwards compatibility with some styles. That issue should definitely have its own question and answer, and not just the "make sure the `biblatex` and Biber versions match" answer.

Comment: Would it make sense to add this sort of thing to Alan Munn's answer to: "[bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)"? Or does it need something more specific than that?

Comment: @Davïd I think the idea was to have a question dedicated to the version problem. The answer is great, but I don't think a user will want to read through the entire thing just to find out about the version problem.

Comment: Any thoughts on what the question should or need not include are welcome, though I'm inclined to the view that it should be made CW, so later edits would be welcome too.

Comment: I agree that a separate question should be created. Given the current issues with `biblatex` and backward compatibility I suggest something like "After update my biblatex document no longer compiles".

Comment: @AlanMunn -- That's a good title, actually. (Much better than the one I thought of last night....)